# Facebook search no longer contextualized?

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api

up to a few days ago, when using Graph API search, the results were contextualized to the current user. For example, being logged in with my user so using my access token, calling a search with q=Massimo&type=user returned friends of mine named Massimo, followed by other people called Massimo, but friends of mine were above other results.

Today it just returns random people, the search seems not to be contextualized anymore.

Were there some changes? Are there new search options to get the contextualized results as opposed to generic ones? Was it a policy change for some reason? Or is it simply a side effect or a temporary problem?

TIA

EDIT:

Clarification : the search box inside the Facebook site itself, still returns contextualized content. Previously, a call to the search system via graph api returned more or less the same results, tailored to the user.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Search results are cached by query and not the user searching for something. That means the first time someone searches for something it's cached by facebook. Later, if someone else searches for the same thing, they will get similar results (not always tailored to their account). Privacy settings play a role (e.g. what information is visible and if the user can be searched). but in general, the results will be the same.

You can test this by searching for the same user using two different access tokens. The results will be relatively the same, even if one user is a friend and the other is not.

E.g. Using User A, search for User C (A and C are friends). Check the results.
Then, search for User C, but using User B (B and C are NOT friends). The results should be relatively the same (if not exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Niraj. I can assure that it was not this way a few weeks ago, if I searched for "Arianna" using graph api from my app, using an auth token on my account, my girlfriend was the first result, followed by others Arianna in my friends list, then by others random people. This is exactly what still happens if I search "Arianna" in the search box inside Facebook site itself. Do you know if this chaching system you're talking about has been introduced around a month ago?

Comment: As far as I know, this caching system has always been in place, but FB could have made some unannounced tweaks to it, which is affecting your app.